# Why firefox is failing to launch on tablet using the below code

Tags: android, selenium, firefox, webdriver, tablet

This code is failing to launch firefox rowser app on android tablet. Can anyone please advice why this is not launchig the firefox app. its working for chrome.

```
 package HelloWorldMobileTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Openfirefox {
WebDriver driver; 

    @BeforeTest public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException { 

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ac5b9732"); 
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Firefox");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.2"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test public void Sum()

    { 

        }

    @AfterTest public void End() { driver.quit(); 

     } 
}
```

Comment: If i change browser_name to CHROME this work properly without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium doesn't support other than chrome as default browser. Firefox even if launched as an app, its not supported by appium and after launch firefox is reclosed.